# Can time fleet?

Tags: grammaticality

I was listening to a song and there was the line "time's fleeting away" which struck me as wrong by ear. I always thought that fleeting was exclusively an adjective and not a verb, but I am not positive. Was the line in the song wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To fleet** can be a intransitive verb according to [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fleet):

> intransitive verb.
>   1 obsolete :  drift
>   2a archaic :  flow
>   2b :  to fade away :  vanish

Comment: Does that mean that "time's fleeting away" is right or wrong?

Comment: It is fine, like time flowing away.